# Extended definition of measurable function

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $(X, \Sigma,\mu)$ be a measure space. Usually, a function $f:X \to [0, \infty]$ is called measurable if $f^{-1}(V) \in \Sigma$ for every open set $V$.

In Rudin's R&C Analysis, the author first defines measurable functions this way. Later he says we can enlarge the class of measurable functions by calling a function defined on a set $E \in \Sigma$ measurable on $X$ if $\mu(E^C)=0$ and $f^{-1}(V) \cap E \in \Sigma$ for every open set $V$.

Before giving this  definition, Rudin talks about the completion of a measure and says that whenever it is convenient, we can assume our measure is complete. Assuming this is the case, his new definition of measurable function is equivalent to the old one.

Rudin's Lebesgue Dominated Convergence Theorem:
Suppose $\{f_n\}$ is a sequence of complex measurable functions defined a.e. on $X$, $g \in L^1(\mu)$ and $|f_n| \le g$ a.e. Then $f=\lim\ f_n$ is defined a.e. on $X$, $f \in L^1(\mu)$, and $\int_X f d\mu=\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_X f_n d\mu$.

So, my questions are:

$1)$ Is it correct to define the integral of these new measurable functions $f$ as $\int_X f d\mu := \int_X g d\mu$ where $g$ is any measurable function that agree a.e. with $f$?

$2)$ Regarding LDCT, where we have a.e., some other books would just redefine the functions involved, over a null set as to obtain existence/convergence everywhere. Do we need a complete measure to perform such operation? Is Rudin's version, using the new definition of measurable function, equivalent to this one?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For what regards the first question: if two (integrable) functions $f_1,f_2$ agree a.e., then their integral over the same set is equal.

As for the second question, you usually complete the measure in order to be able to deal with "null sets" in an efficient way. Otherwise, you could have subsets of a zero-measure set that are not themselves measurable, and this is quite disappointing.

Moral: whenever possible, work with complete measure.

UPDATE: The following theorem holds:
Let $(X_1,\mathcal{M}_1,\mu_1),(X_2,\mathcal{M}_2,\mu_2)$ be $\sigma$-finite measure spaces. Let $\mathcal{A}$ be the completion of the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{M}_1\otimes\mathcal{M}_2$ w.r.t. the measure $\mu_1\otimes \mu_2$. Let $f$ be an $\mathcal{A}$-measurable function. Then, the Fubini-Tonelli Theorem holds and the integral functions there involved are defined a.e. with respect to the relative measures.